# Reset TranslateZoomRotateBehavior? (WPF/Blend behavior)

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, behavior

I have attached a TranslateZoomRotateBehavior to a Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <!--all sorts of content-->
    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click Width="25" Height="20"/>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:TranslateZoomRotateBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" SupportedGestures="Translate"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

in the CancelButton_Click eventhandler I want to reset the TranslateZoomRotateBehavior to return the Grid and it's content to it's original position. Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name the grid that you want to reset the behaviours collection on.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
```

You can get a list of the behaviors in code behind with

```
var b = System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.GetBehaviors(grid1)
```

You're then free to work with them however you want, if you want to remove them all .Clear() if you want to reset just values but keep the TranslateZoomRotateBehavior you can access it with

```
TranslateZoomRotateBehavior targetBehavior = (TranslateZoomRotateBehavior)b[0];
targetBehavior.ConstrainToParentBounds = true;
targetBehavior.SupportedGestures = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

`TranslateZoomRotateBehavior` is adding `MatrixTransform` to element it is attached to.

So modifying your example:

```
<Grid Name="TestGrid">
    <!--all sorts of content-->
    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click Width="25" Height="20"/>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:TranslateZoomRotateBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" SupportedGestures="Translate"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

Then you can reset it in code the following way:

```
TestGrid.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform();
```